# Unknown database type geometry requested error in doctirne:mapping:import for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sql-server-2012

I'm getting the following error while running the doctrine:mapping:import command in Symfony2. I'm using SQL Server 2012 even though the error says " 2008Platform may not support it".

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
  Unknown database type geometry requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\SQLServer  
  2008Platform may not support it.
```

My database configuration look like this:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   pdo_sqlsrv
    host:     localhost
    port:     1433
    dbname:   test
    user:     user
    password: password
    charset:  UTF8
```

I have also tried setting the mapping type to string. But it gives the same error.

When I try the command using MyMainBundle string --force. I get this error:

```
 [Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Export\ExportException]          
  The specified export driver 'string' does not exist
```

I have used the driver [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) for php.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message one of the tables for which you're trying to import the schema contains a column of type geometry. Afaik Doctrine2 does not support the Geometry type out of the box (hopefully that will change soon).

One thing that might help would be to create a custom mapping type, as described here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html

Another option you could try is the doctrine-spatial bundle, found here: https://github.com/djlambert/doctrine2-spatial

Not sure if this works with a mssql-based server though...

Comment: I'm sure I do not have a geometry type column

Answer (score 0):

I've just met similar issue which was caused by already existing tables in public schema (tables like geography_columns created during PostGIS installation).

As a solution I skip using schema "public" for my app and store tables/entities in e.g. "main" schema..